# How do I update a Redux store value on a timer?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm playing around with a bit more of reudx and I'm trying to display a value which works. The initial state is set to 0.

My goal is to increment this value by 1 every second. To accomplish this I did something like this:

```
  setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(Increment());
  }, 1000);
```

It's not really working the way I want it to, even though it increments, it does it at an extremely fast pace.

Also, another question. Inside my reducer I would in theory like to make expressions like this:

```
Increment: (state) => {
      state.value + 1;
    },
```

But when I do this redux throws the following error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Is it not possible to make such expressions inside a redux reducer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your function here does not have a return statement

```
Increment: (state) => {
  state.value + 1;
},
```

try to change it to

```
Increment: (state) => {
  return state.value + 1;
},
```

or use parenthesis () to instead of using {()}

```
Increment: (state) => (
  state.value + 1;
),
```

And also don't forget that reducers are pure functions
.............................................................

your reducer should be something like this

```
const initialState = { count: 0 };
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
     case 'INCREMENT':  
       return {         
        count: state.count + 1       
      };     
     case 'DECREMENT':       
       return {         
       count: state.count - 1       
      };     
     default:       
       return state;   
  } 
}
```

you should then have an action that you dispatch with a type like this

```
dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'})
```

since you already have an action helper function

it goes like this

```
function increment() {
   return {
   type: "INCREMENT"
  } 
};

function decrement() {
   return {
   type: "DECREMENT"
  } 
};
```

then you can do this

```
 setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(increment());
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried doing that. What happens then is that my variable goes from it's initial state to being blank. It's no longer rendered on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for that update. I've set up my reducer according to Redux tutorial page. I do not understand how I can implement your code into my own. This whole redux thing is still very new to me.
`export const copperReducer = createSlice({
  name: "copper",
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    copperIncrement: (state) => {
      state.value + 1;
    },
    copperDecrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
  },
});

export const { copperIncrement, copperDecrement } = copperReducer.actions;

export default copperReducer.reducer;`

Comment: nice, hope your code is working as expected?.. if not we can hookup on a zoom call, if you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

`state.value + 1` creates a number that is 1 more than `state.value` but you don't *do anything* with that value.  When it says "expected an assignment" it means that you expected to assign the created number to a variable like `const someVariable = state.value + 1`.

There are [certain operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#assignment_operators) which combine the assignment with the operation.  You don't need to create a new variable because those operators update the value of the existing variable.  That's what you want to do here.  You can use the [addition assignment operator `+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) like this: `state.value += 5`. Or you can add 1 with the [increment operator `++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) just by writing `state.value++`.  Both of these operations modify the `state.value` property of your draft state.

You should read this guide:

- [MDN Javascript Guide: Expressions and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

---

As far as updating on a timer, you want to initiatiate the `setInterval` call inside of a `useEffect` hook.  You want to store the id of the created interval so that you can stop the dispatching by calling `clearInterval` when the component unmounts or if a "Stop" button is pressed.

Here is an example code:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } from "../store/slice";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "../store";

export const Counter = () => {
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);

  const intervalId = useRef<number>();

  useEffect(() => {
    // helper function to stop an existing timer
    const clear = () => {
      if (intervalId.current) {
        clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      }
    };

    // start the timer
    if (isRunning) {
      intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
        dispatch(increment());
      }, 1000);
    }
    // stop the timer when isRunning becomed false
    else {
      clear();
    }

    // cleanup function stops the timer when the component unmounts
    return clear;
  }, [dispatch, isRunning]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setIsRunning(true)} disabled={isRunning}>
          Start Timer
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setIsRunning(false)} disabled={!isRunning}>
          Stop Timer
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-counter-with-timer-h9r52?file=/src/components/App.tsx:0-1908)